# Como descobrir se a sessão expirou?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Preciso descobrir quando a sessão expira, em ASP.Net MVC, pra eu mostrar um modal e redirecionar.

Como eu posso fazer isso?

Tem algo no `httpcontext` que eu posso usar?

Comment: O que você quer fazer? mostrar uma modal para o usuário dizer que quer permanecer logado ou exibir uma modal falando que ele foi deslogado por desuso?

Comment: Desculpe, acho que não me expressei direito rs
Eu quero mostrar uma modal pro usuário avisando que ele foi deslogado por desuso, em seguida redirecionar ele pra página de login.

Answer (score 1):

Para verificar se a sessão ainda é válida basta verificar a propriedade:  `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`.

E faça o código que pretende de acordo com o resultado. *(modal, redirecionamento)*

Recomendo que veja a [documentação oficial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) para mais detalhes e exemplos.

Comment: Colega, me corrija se estiver errado, mas a propriedade `IsAuthenticated` somente verifica se o usuário esta autenticado, e não que a sessão seja valida, ou seja diferente de null

Comment: Sim, @ThomasErichPimentel, `isAuthenticated` verifica se está autenticado justamente verificando se a sessão daquele usuário ainda é válida. O tempo da sessão deve ser definido de outra forma como `Session.Timeout = 60;` recomendo que veja a [documentação a respeito](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Como o servidor não tem uma conexão persistente com o cliente você pode criar um timer em javascript com o mesmo tempo de duração da session no seu servidor.

Ao atingir esse tempo você exibe a modal e ao fechar a modal você pode redirecioná-lo para a tela de login. Não importa se passou alguns segundos a mais ou não, desde que a sessão no servidor não exista mais, ele será redirecionado, se você fez as validações corretas...

Nesse caso não tem com o que se preocupar, mas se ainda quiser desloga-lo, ao atingir o tempo você pode usar uma chamada em ajax (preferência post) em uma simples action que deleta a session.